# How to determine uncertainty of data from a bayesian posterior distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, posterior, uncertainty

I am a bit confused as to how we determine the uncertainty of a set of data from Bayesian Analysis.

In my specific case, I am asked the following:

> *Assume $f(x,x_0)$ as the correct model for the observed data and the following likelihood for each datapoint:
> $$p(y(x)) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp (- \frac{(y(x)- f(x,x_0)^2)}{\sigma^2})$$
> Determine the posterior probability distribution for $x_0$, with respect to the dataset $(x,y)$ and make a plot of it. Determine also its mode and the smallest interval in $x_0$ that contains 95% of the posterior probability. Construct a plot that allows the visualization of the values observed for $y(x)$, including the uncertainty associated with each
> point, as well as the model prediction $f(x,x_0)$, assuming that $x_0$ is equal to the mode previously obtained, and to the lower and upper limits of the confidence interval of the posterior probability.*

In order to do this, I calculated the posterior distribution of the parameter $x_0$, given the model and the data (considering a normalized uniform prior and the total likelihood as the product over all observed data of the likelihood shown above), arriving at the following distribution (N is just a constant from the uniform prior and marginalization):

$$p(x_0|D,M) = \frac{1}{N} \left ( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt 2} \right )^N \exp \left (- \sum_i^N \frac{(y(x_i) - f(x_i,x_0))^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right )$$

(represented bellow is the $\log_{10}$ of the distribution):

[image: Log10 of Posterior Distribution]

I then calculated the mode and $95 \%$ confidence interval of the distribution, assuming the most credible value for $x_0$ is the mode and its uncertainty is half the length of the confidence interval: $$x_0 = 97.71 \pm 0.04$$

Now, to determine the uncertainty of the data, I was going to just calculate its deviation from the model given the value found for $x_0$ ($y-f(x,x_0)$) but I'm not sure this is the most correct approach, since I am not using the confidence interval in any way to determine this 'uncertainty'.

What is the most correct way to determine the uncertainty of each point in the data in this cenario?

Comment: How much data deviate from the model is not “uncertainty of the data”. You can have the poor model and it will deviate a lot from the data, no matter how certain or uncertain your data is. Uncertainty of the data would rather be something like measurement error.

Comment: Yes, but in this specific case I don't have measurement error. The goal of is to determine an uncertainty for the data based solely on bayesian analysis

Comment: What do you mean by “uncertainty of the data” then?

Comment: That plot obviously isn't of a Normal distribution: its values are negative and a *logarithmic* plot would be perfectly parabolic, which this isn't.  What is it intended to represent?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer: the plot I'm showing is the $log_{10}$ of the distribution

Comment: Then--because it's not anything like a parabola--it's *definitely* not Normal!  How was this plot computed?  (One definition of a Normal distribution is that it's--literally--any distribution whose log density plots as a parabola.)

Comment: I am concerned that some mistake has been made in the calculations and that this plot does not reflect your question and that your question might not correctly represent what you have done.  To avoid receiving answers that might lead you astray and potentially confuse other readers, I am voting to close this question until you have had an opportunity to clarify the details: namely, how you obtain these points, how you fit the model, and what the plot actually shows.

Comment: I don't see how the computation of the plot is relevant since my question is very conceptual - i want to know how to extrapolate uncertainty of data from bayesian analysis, the plot is just an example from the exercise I'm working on

Comment: regardless of that, I've added the expression of the plot to the post

Comment: Consistency is crucial because a lack of it means different people are likely to understand and interpret the question differently.  It also suggests you aren't asking the question you really need to ask.  Your language is also confusing: you ask about "uncertainty of the data" but your graph purports to display uncertainty in *the estimate of the parameter.*

Comment: I would like to be clearer, but 'uncertainty of the data' is precisely the language used in the exercise, which also made me confused, which is why I asked. I can add the full enunciate of the exercise to the question, maybe that can help

Comment: Yes, it almost always helps to quote an exercise *verbatim,* because many times the difficulty is caused by a misreading or misinterpretation of the exercise text.  And please apply the [tag:self-study] tag to your post.